# Angular2 how to initialize array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, object, initialization

I would like to know how to initialize an array of object, in order to push in it later.
I have :
`tab:[{tel:number,name:String}];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
tab:{tel:number, name:string}[] = [];
```

Check the TypeScript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) of basic types